# TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 896372 bytes

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

```
mBinding.attachBtn.setOnClickListener {
        mGetContent.launch("image/*")
    }
```

This is the launch code

```
mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        ActivityResultCallback {
            val intent = Intent(APP_ACTIVITY, CropperAcrtivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("DATA", it.toString())
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
        })
```

Initializing mGetContent

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == -1 && requestCode == 101) {
        var result = data!!.getStringExtra("RESULT")
        var resultUri: Uri = Uri.parse(result)
        var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(APP_ACTIVITY.contentResolver, resultUri)
        sendMessageAsImage(bitmap)
    }
}
```

Getting the result

### The essence of the problem

I'm trying to send images to the chat room, but when I did it through sending URI, the message is written once in the database, but in the Recycler View is displayed 3 times, or the error TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 896372 bytes, now I do through bitmap and this error has not gone anywhere, it appears immediately after running "image / *" I do not even have time to choose a photo from the memory

UPD: Sending an image

```
mBinding.uploadBtn.setOnClickListener {
        uploadImageMessage()
    }
```

uploadImageMessage

```
private fun uploadImageMessage(){
    val message = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
    message.put(KEY_IS_CHECKED, false)
    message.put(SENDER_ID, preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
    message.put(RECEIVER_ID, receiverUser.uid)
    message.put(KEY_MESSAGE, mBinding.textImages.text)
    message.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, Date())
    message.put(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE, MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE)
    database.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .whereEqualTo(KEY_UID, preferenceManager.getString(KEY_UID))
        .get().addOnCompleteListener {
            it.getResult().documents.get(0).reference.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .add(message)
        }
    mBinding.frameTypeField.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.sendBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.frameAttach.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.cancelBtn.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.uploadBtn.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.iconImage.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.textImages.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.typeMessageField.setText(null)
}
```

sendMessageAsImage

```
private fun sendMessageAsImage(image: Bitmap) {
    mBinding.frameTypeField.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.sendBtn.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.frameAttach.visibility = View.GONE
    mBinding.cancelBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.uploadBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.iconImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.textImages.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    mBinding.textImages.text = encodedImage(image).toString()
}
```

Before I used to send a picture to the database in the sendMessageAsImage function, but because the messages were for some reason displayed three times on the screen I decided to split the function and now sending is done by clicking on uploadBtn

Comment: None of the code you've shown interacts with your savedInstanceState at all; some other code must be where you are passing a large amount of data through an Intent or Bundle.

Comment: Posting the stacktrace will help in solving the problem. I suspect that it has to do with `sendMessageAsImage(bitmatp)`; so it would also help if you can add the code for that method.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 I added in UPD

Comment: If you would like to try using Jetpack Compose, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) might help.

Comment: @Danil Did you managed to fix the issue? I got almost the same one.

Comment: @DzikiArbuz nope(